# Why does a search term with an ampersand get truncated?

Tags: google-search

Go to [Google Image Search](http://www.google.com/imghp) and put this in the search criteria (remove the double quotes and make sure there is a trailing space):

> "d&d animated series "

Search gets truncated to "D". Why?

Comment: Odd. Not just this search argument though; it's everything containing a `&` and ending in a space. And the truncation doesn't happen when you do a normal search first and then switch to "images". Maybe you should file a bug report with Google.

Comment: @MrLister [Done.](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/websearch/unexpected-search-results/2kbHLSd3Lsc) Thanks for helping me confirm.

Comment: this is no longer the case: `https://www.google.com/search?num=10&hl=en&newwindow=1&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1378&bih=815&q=d%26d+animated+series&oq=d%26d+animated+series&gs_l=img.3..0i24l2.1532.5160.0.5641.23.10.2.11.12.0.132.598.9j1.10.0...0.0...1ac.1.KXLhkOPMH0I#hl=en&newwindow=1&site=imghp&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%E2%80%9Cd%26d+animated+series+%E2%80%9D&oq=%E2%80%9Cd%26d+animated+series+%E2%80%9D&gs_l=img.3..0i24.8301.8301.0.9180.1.1.0.0.0.0.69.69.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.pjO_DW9whRo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=4e3453919e235572&bpcl=35466521&biw=1378&bih=815`

Comment: This *is* still the case. I'm trying to search for help with an Angular error (`export 'core_private' (imported as 'r') was not found in '@angular/core`), and this exact problem occurs. I've seen it several times lately. Please vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the search results, put your query again in the search box. It will work this time.

This is probably a google images bug